# учебное задание на ассемблере (микроконтроллер 8051)

Tags: ассемблер, микроконтроллеры, 8051

Реализовать программу: пользователь устанавливает в Р0 некоторое число N. Программа должна занести в стек натуральные числа от 1 до N. После этого, вынимая их поочередно из стека, сосчитать их сумму и вывести ее в портах Р1 (младший байт) и Р2 (старший байт).

Какое максимальное число может быть в Р0, чтобы программа корректно работала?

Comment: Это число - 255, или 0xFF, или 0b11111111

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос с подвохом: максимальное число ограничено размером стека. Его максимальное значение на 8051-архитектуре 96 байт, т.е. ответ 96. Сумма при этом меньше 65535, т.е. на порты ее вывести можно.